# how to change color of line chart in highchart based on a categorical column in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, highcharts, visualization

I am trying to create an interactive line chart using `highcharts` and change the color of lines based on a categorical column i.e `CFR_level`.

**Below is the ggplot (desired form of non interactive version)**

```
p1_cfr <- grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region %in% top_10) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Confirmed, col = CFR_level, group = Country.Region, label = continent)) +
  geom_path() 

p1_cfr
```

[image]

**Issue**: When I am trying to convert this to interactive plot using **highcharts** its not coloring the lines based on categorical variable i.e `CFR_level` but rather coloring based on each `Country.Region`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
```

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region %in% top_10) %>%
  
  hchart(type = "line", hcaes(x = Date, y = Confirmed, group = Country.Region, color = CFR_level))
```

[image]

How do I color each line in `highchart` based on categorical variable `CFR_level` ?

```
      ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Updated (Data details):**

```
top_10

######### output ##########

 [1] "US"            
 [2] "India"         
 [3] "Brazil"        
 [4] "Russia"        
 [5] "France"        
 [6] "United Kingdom"
 [7] "Italy"         
 [8] "Turkey"        
 [9] "Spain"         
[10] "Argentina"
```

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region %in% top_10) %>%
  head(n = 30)

####### output #########

   Country.Region continent Date       Confirmed Deaths Case_Fatality_Ratio CFR_level
   <chr>          <fct>     <date>         <int>  <int>               <dbl> <fct>    
 1 Argentina      Americas  2020-01-22         0      0                   0 Low      
 2 Argentina      Americas  2020-01-23         0      0                   0 Low      
 3 Argentina      Americas  2020-01-24         0      0                   0 Low      
 4 Argentina      Americas  2020-01-25         0      0                   0 Low      
 5 Argentina      Americas  2020-01-26         0      0                   0 Low      
 6 Argentina      Americas  2020-01-27         0      0                   0 Low      
 7 Argentina      Americas  2020-01-28         0      0                   0 Low      
 8 Argentina      Americas  2020-01-29         0      0                   0 Low      
 9 Argentina      Americas  2020-01-30         0      0                   0 Low      
10 Argentina      Americas  2020-01-31         0      0                   0 Low      
# ... with 20 more rows
```

```
grouped_cases_df %>% str()

####### output #########

tibble [64,176 x 7] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Country.Region     : chr [1:64176] "Afghanistan" "Afghanistan" "Afghanistan" "Afghanistan" ...
 $ continent          : Factor w/ 6 levels "Africa","Americas",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Date               : Date[1:64176], format: "2020-01-22" "2020-01-23" "2020-01-24" ...
 $ Confirmed          : int [1:64176] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Deaths             : int [1:64176] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Case_Fatality_Ratio: num [1:64176] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CFR_level          : Factor w/ 3 levels "Low","Med","High": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region %in% top_10) %>% 
  str()

####### output #########

tibble [3,360 x 7] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Country.Region     : chr [1:3360] "Argentina" "Argentina" "Argentina" "Argentina" ...
 $ continent          : Factor w/ 6 levels "Africa","Americas",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Date               : Date[1:3360], format: "2020-01-22" "2020-01-23" "2020-01-24" ...
 $ Confirmed          : int [1:3360] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Deaths             : int [1:3360] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Case_Fatality_Ratio: num [1:3360] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CFR_level          : Factor w/ 3 levels "Low","Med","High": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region %in% top_10) %>%
  summary()

####### output #########

 Country.Region        continent         Date              Confirmed            Deaths      
 Length:3360        Africa  :   0   Min.   :2020-01-22   Min.   :       0   Min.   :     0  
 Class :character   Americas:1008   1st Qu.:2020-04-14   1st Qu.:   46875   1st Qu.:  1382  
 Mode  :character   Asia    : 336   Median :2020-07-07   Median :  283225   Median : 26286  
                    Europe  :2016   Mean   :2020-07-07   Mean   : 1338426   Mean   : 39411  
                    Oceania :   0   3rd Qu.:2020-09-29   3rd Qu.: 1344549   3rd Qu.: 41590  
                    Unknown :   0   Max.   :2020-12-22   Max.   :18230242   Max.   :322765  
 Case_Fatality_Ratio CFR_level  
 Min.   : 0.000      Low : 455  
 1st Qu.: 1.746      Med : 719  
 Median : 2.791      High:2186  
 Mean   : 4.722                 
 3rd Qu.: 6.214                 
 Max.   :23.835
```

**Update 2 (reply to "coloredline")**

I have tried couple of methods as you suggested but I am not sure why I get blank lines, even though those data points exist there

1.

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 

  # filtering only couple of countries for simplicity
  filter(Country.Region %in% c("France","India")) %>%
  
  hchart(type = "coloredline", 
         hcaes(x = Date, y = Confirmed, group = Country.Region, segmentColor = CFR_level)) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Low", 
                color = "green", marker = list(symbol = "line")) %>% 
  
  hc_add_series(name = "Med", 
                color = "yellow", marker = list(symbol = "line")) %>% 
  
  hc_add_series(name = "High", 
                color = "red", marker = list(symbol = "line")) %>% 
  
  hc_add_dependency("plugins/multicolor_series.js")
```

[image]

2. Inspired from shared source link

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region %in% c("France","India")) %>%
  
  hchart(type = "coloredline", 
         hcaes(x = Date, y = Confirmed, group = Country.Region, segmentColor = CFR_level)) %>%
  hc_add_dependency("plugins/multicolor_series.js")
```

[image]

3. If I use `hc_add_series(data = .,` then I get error

**Solution update** (thanks to @Ben suggestions)

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region %in% top_10) %>%
  mutate(CFR_col = case_when(CFR_level == "Low" ~ "#FFFF00",
                         CFR_level == "Med" ~ "#008000",
                         TRUE ~ "#FF0000")
         ) %>% 
  
  hchart(type = "coloredline", 
         hcaes(x = Date, y = Confirmed, group = Country.Region, segmentColor = CFR_col)) %>%
  hc_add_dependency("plugins/multicolor_series.js")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share either a sample dataset, or at least the result of str() for the dataframe before and after the `grouped_cases_df %>% ` command?

Comment: Hi @Ben, I have **Updated** `str()`, `summary()`, `head()` of the dataset but I am not sure how helpful these will be as this dataset is covid data for multiple countries over the whole year. Wish I could have shared the complete data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see brief mention of similar problem as highcharter github issue [here](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/180).

I am using the `COVID19` package to have some readily available data to use as illustration. I hypothetically set a few countries to different `CFR_level` values as examples (this is just to demonstrate, they do not reflect actual case fatality rates).

With `hchart` use `coloredline` and `multicolor_series` module, which allows for individual `segmentColor` values to be used (more [info and examples here on plugins and modules](https://jkunst.com/highcharter/articles/modules.html)). Then, you can use a column for `group` and a different column for `segmentColor`.

In addition, I included `hc_add_series` with empty data to add a custom legend.

**Edit (12/24/20)**: If you set `color` in `hcaes` in `hchart` you can get the tooltip hover color to match based on `CFR_level`. For this example, I put the colors in hex equivalents (`CFR_level` in this case is a color and not a character value).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(COVID19)

df <- covid19()    
            
df$CFR_level <- "#008000"
df$CFR_level[df$id == "IND"] <- "#FFFF00"
df$CFR_level[df$id == "USA"] <- "#FF0000"

df %>%
  filter(id %in% c("USA", "BRA", "RUS", "IND")) %>%
  hchart(type = "coloredline", 
         hcaes(x = date, y = confirmed, group = id, color = CFR_level, segmentColor = CFR_level),
         showInLegend = F) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Low", color = "#008000", marker = list(symbol = "line")) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Med", color = "#FFFF00", marker = list(symbol = "line")) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "High", color = "#FF0000", marker = list(symbol = "line")) %>% 
  hc_add_dependency("plugins/multicolor_series.js")
```

**Plot**

[image: highcharter plot]

Comment: Thanks alot @Ben for putting in so much effort to pull the data and recreate the whole task & sharing those source links, I really really appreciate. I am facing an issue of blank line with it which I have further added to the original post as **update 2  (reply to "coloredline")**

Comment: And another thing I have noticed now is in my first original post by using `color = CFR_level` it changes the color of `tooltip` based on `CFR_level` when hovered over the line

Comment: Looking at your example, did you set `CFR_level` to colors like I have? For example, if your `CFR_level` is "low" for a particular country or region, those `CFR_level` values should be a color, such as `#008000` and not the character "low".

Comment: Hi @Ben, yes now it worked after setting color. I will also add the solution code & image to the post. Thank you so so much for helping me out :)